# Select rows by partial string match in index

Tags: python, pandas

Having a series like this:

```
ds = Series({'wikipedia':10,'wikimedia':22,'wikitravel':33,'google':40})

google        40
wikimedia     22
wikipedia     10
wikitravel    33
dtype: int64
```

I would like to select the rows where 'wiki' is a part of the index label (a partial string label).

For the moment I tried

```
ds[ds.index.map(lambda x: 'wiki' in x)]

wikimedia     22
wikipedia     10
wikitravel    33
Name: site, dtype: int64
```

and it does the job, but somehow the index cries for 'contains' just like what the columns have...

Any better way to do that?

Answer (score 21):

A somewhat cheeky way could be to use `loc`:

```
In [11]: ds.loc['wiki': 'wikj']
Out[11]:
wikimedia     22
wikipedia     10
wikitravel    33
dtype: int64
```

*This is essentially equivalent to `ds[ds.index.map(lambda s: s.startswith('wiki'))]`.*

To do contains, as @DSM suggests, it's probably nicer to write as:

```
ds[['wiki' in s for s in ds.index]]
```

Comment: Heh, nice trick, that's true, but it only does 'startwith' operation. Not 'contains'. Or am I wrong?

Comment: There's `ds.irow(Series(ds.index).str.contains("wiki"))`, but I think I prefer a simple `ds[['wiki' in x for x in ds.index]]`.  BTW, I think there are some bugs lurking here: `list(ds.str)` seems to go on forever.

Comment: @DSM thought I'd pop it as [an issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3638) anyways.

Comment: @DSM ...[so come 11.1](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/3645) `list(ds.str)` won't crash. Thanks! :)

Comment: plus one for @DSM ds[['wiki' in s for s in ds.index]] 'feels' the best/most flexible.

Answer (score 19):

An alternative (to [Andy Hayden's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16617491/13258525)) using `filter`, see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
>>> ds.filter(like='wiki', axis=0)
wikimedia     22
wikipedia     10
wikitravel    33
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

From the original question:

> "...index cries for 'contains' just like what the columns have".

I'm not sure when this was added (this is an old question), but you can now use `contains` on `index.str` assuming your index is a string type:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> ds = pd.Series({'wikipedia':10,'wikimedia':22,'wikitravel':33,'google':40})
>>> ds[ds.index.str.contains("wiki")]

wikipedia     10
wikimedia     22
wikitravel    33
dtype: int64
```